# CORS issue with Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, cors, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, whitelist

I'm developing a Cordova application. Inside my app I'm using InAppBrowser and there are many Ajax requests from InAppBrowser. I've whitelisted all URL's in config but still I'm getting CORS issue. Probably It's because whitelisting doesn't apply for InAppBrowser. How to resolve this without using JSONP or modifying server?

Comment: Does your REST service allows CORS requests?

Comment: Yes it allows. But still it is not working.

Comment: yes,whitelisting doesn't apply for InAppBrowser.I think you should enable cors in [your server](http://enable-cors.org/).and add session/token system to recognize the call from inAppBrowser to avoid abuse of your service.